# How to convert date strings to different format using Calendar

Tags: java, date, time, calendar

I am changing to `Calendar` from the deprecated `Date` library, I need to compare different time string objects.

How can I transform the time string `(xx:xx:xx)` to a full date `(Tue Feb 03 21:02:25 CET 2015)` using `Calendar`?

I tried:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Test2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        // Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").parse("21:20:00"); // Date ist 1970!
        // System.out.println(date.toString());

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss | dd.MM.yy");
        cal.set(cal.YEAR, cal.MONTH, cal.DATE, 21, 20, 00);
        System.out.println(sdf2.format(cal.getTime()));

    }

}
```

and

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Test2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        // Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").parse("21:20:00"); // Date ist 1970!
        // System.out.println(date.toString());

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss | dd.MM.yy");
        cal.setTime(sdf.parse("21:20:00"));
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.DATE);
        System.out.println(sdf2.format(cal.getTime()));

    }

}
```

But they return, respectively: `21:20:00 | 05.03.01`

I want to be able to compare the result with other "full date objects" like `Tue Feb 03 21:02:25 CET 2015`.

Comment: This may come off as rude, but... Have you tried reading the Javadoc on the `set` method you invoke? And how exactly are you going to compare a time of day with a date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Upated:**

```
// Set the time in String
String stringDate = "04:10:13";
// Parse this time 
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
// Set the parsed time to a Calendar object
cal.setTime(sdf.parse(stringDate));
```

Now you have to get the today's date and set the above time to it using `Calendar#set` method.

```
// get today's time
Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
// print today date with current time,
System.out.println("Date before time is set: " + today.getTime());

// set today's hour to above time
today.set(Calendar.HOUR, cal.get(Calendar.HOUR));
// set today's minute to above time
today.set(Calendar.MINUTE, cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
// set today's seconds to above time
today.set(Calendar.SECOND, cal.get(Calendar.SECOND));
// print your new time
System.out.println("Date after time is set: " + today.getTime());
```

***Output:***

```
Date before time is set: Thu Feb 05 02:52:55 PKT 2015
Date after time is set: Thu Feb 05 04:10:13 PKT 2015
```

You can also set time in one line,

```
today.set(today.get(Calendar.YEAR), today.get(Calendar.MONTH) , today.get(Calendar.DATE), cal.get(Calendar.HOUR), cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE), cal.get(Calendar.SECOND));
```

Comment: String stringDate = "04:10:13";
results in: 
"Date after time is set: Tue Feb 03 16:10:13 CET 2015"
but it SHOULD be: 
"Date after time is set: Tue Feb 03 04:10:13 CET 2015"

Comment: Ahhhh, thats working :)! Thanks you :)! Already accepted your answer, cant upvote it, cause Iam too know. But Ill do it, if I get the missing points :). Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

Use [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)

**Build a DateTime from current time**

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime()
            .withMillisOfSecond(0)
            .withHourOfDay(21)
            .withMinuteOfHour(20)
            .withSecondOfMinute(0);
```

**Build a DateTime from pattern**

```
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(<YOUR_PATTERN>);
DateTime dt2 = dateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(<YOUR_DATE_IN_A_STRING>);
```

**Compare DateTimes**

```
if(dt.isAfter(dt2)){
    // DO ANYTHING
} else if(dt.isBefore(dt2){
    // DO WHATEVER
}
```

**Get a Date from DateTime**

```
Date date = dt.toDate()
```

Comment: I suggest specifying the time zone ([`DateTimeZone`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html)). Otherwise your DateTime is assigned the JVM’s current default time zone. So your results will vary by which computer it runs on, the computer's time zone set when JVM launched, or when some other Java code in this JVM calls [`TimeZone.setDefault`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#setDefault-java.util.TimeZone-).

Answer (score -2):

LocalDateTime (http://www.journaldev.com/2800/java-8-date-time-api-example-tutorial-localdate-instant-localdatetime-parse-and-format) helped me here:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String time = "14:12:01";
        String[] timePieces= time.split(":");
        int H = Integer.parseInt(timePieces[0]);
        int m = Integer.parseInt(timePieces[1]);
        int s = Integer.parseInt(timePieces[2]);

        LocalDateTime today = LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.now(), LocalTime.of(H, m, s));
        System.out.println(today);

        LocalDateTime today2 = LocalDateTime.now().withHour(H).withMinute(m).withSecond(s).withNano(0);
        System.out.println(today2);
    }

}
```

To convert it to "Date" object:

```
Date date = Date.from(today.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
```

Comment: Downvote me for sharing my solution... This does really motivate me to help other users... And better dont comment, why you dont like it... Great attitude.

Comment: you are getting down voted because you have asked question on how to use `Calendar` to do this, but your answer does`t answer your original question.

Comment: Oh, I thought I can mark 2 as correct...^^ Changed back to yours, you are right :).